# Awk catching lines with certain format

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I have a file full of lines and I want to catch lines with certain format, using awk.

**Input**

```
text that I dont want
control similar text but not quite
control "1text, numbers 2 and special characters inside quotes %&¤" sometext sometext #-- The desired line
more text I dont want
stuff
```

**Output**

```
control "text inside quotes" sometext sometext
#-- There isn't comments like these in the file, so no need to process them
```

The line would then be stored inside an array with the line number: `MENU[POS'$POS']=$0","NR`

Here's what I've already tried:

```
awk '$0 ~ /^control "[:alpha:]" [:alpha:] [:alpha:]$/ {print}'
awk '$0 ~ /^control "*" * *$/ {print}'
```

Comment: why not selecting `control "similar text" but not quite`?

Comment: `awk '$0 ~ /^control "[a-z ]+" [a-z]+ [a-z]+$/ {print}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a named character class cannot be used alone. It needs to get enclosed between brackets. Otherwise it would get interpreted as the character class `[:alph]` meaning the literal characters `:`, `a`, `l`, `p` and `h`.

Change:

```
[:alpha:]
```

to:

```
[[:alpha:]]
```

---

Secondly it looks like you missed the `+` quantifier after the  `[[:alpha:]]` characters classes. `+` means *one or more*. Also you should additionally match spaces between the quotes. (Since they appear in the test data).

It should be:

```
awk '/^control "[[:alpha:][:space:]]+" [[:alpha:]]+ [[:alpha:]]+$/'
```

Which could be shortened to:

```
awk '/^control "[[:alpha:][:space:]]+"( [[:alpha:]]+){2}$/'
```

---

Btw, as you see, you don't need to write `$0 ~ /REGEX/{print}` in `awk`. You can simply write `/REGEX/` instead. This is because by default the whole record (`$0`) will be subject of pattern matching in `awk`. Also `print` is the default action in `awk`, meaning if a condition evaluates to `true` and no action is specified, `awk` will print the whole record.

Comment: Thanks! :D I didn't know you needed those

Comment: you should allow spaces within the quotes

Comment: More precisely, when you write `[:alpha:]`, it is an ordinary character class with the characters `a`, `h`, `l`, `p` and `:` in it — not the metaclass (named character class); that's `[[:alpha:]]`, as you say.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good explanation. Added that.

Comment: @hek2mgl You can shorten it more by changing `[[:alpha:][:space:]]` to `[[:print:]]` and thanks for the tip on `/REGEX/`. This goes inside a nested if statement so the `$0 ~ /REGEX/` is needed

Comment: @BonBon This would include numbers and special characters. I'm not sure if this is desired.

Comment: @hek2mgl They are allowed, but only for the quoted text. I'll change my question to make that clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jonathan Leffler's comment:

```
awk '$0 ~ /^control "[^"]+"[^"]*$/ { print }'
```

**Output**

> control "text inside quotes" sometext sometext

This looks for lines with control and double quotes, rejecting those with 1, 3 or more quotes.

Comment: Your `$2` match looks for 'zero or more double quotes followed by a double quote'.  It looks as if you're thinking of shell-style globbing where `*` on its own matches zero or more characters. Given that `$2` must contain the starting quote, but `$4` contains the matching end quote, your mistake is fortuitous.  I think you should be thinking in terms of `awk '$1 == "control" && $0 ~ /"[^"]+"/ { print }'` which looks for a pair of double quotes.  You could tweak that to: `awk '/^control "[^"]+"[^"]*$/'` if you want only control lines that contain two double quotes (rejecting those with 1 or 3).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks and yes, this is my first day using awk, with experience on shell type globbing :D I'll correct my answer based on your comment